# New construction home, loose foundation anchor nuts

Tags: foundation, anchor, new-home

I am going around caulking behind the insulation due to drafts. Part of basement sits above ground, as house is built on slope. Many of the nuts on these foundation anchors are loose. I have been tightening them with a socket wrench until firmly but not over doing it.

First are these supposed to be loose? The house is 2yrs old. Did they forget to tighten these or did they come loose as the house settles. Some were sitting halfway up the stem.

How tight should they be?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Perfectly normal, and no cause for worry.  They likely were tight when installed, but the bottom plate has shrunk a bit as it dried out, plus the plate has "settled in" around the high spots of the concrete.  The nuts only serve to keep the house from blowing away in a tornado, and for that duty they need not be tight.  (But I would tighten them a bit anyway, being as CDO as I am.)

Comment: Thanks! Yea that is what I was thinning may have happened.

Comment: OCD compels me to point out @HotLicks  got the order wrong on the acronym unless your talking Collateralized Debt Obligation?

Comment: @Kris - No, CDO is the order the letters OUGHT to be in.

Comment: @HotLicks  ALMO      I guess you  are correct thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they’re suppose to be tight. I suspect they forgot to tighten. I’d hand tighten, plus about a quarter turn.

The anchor bolts and nuts do two things: 1) keep the house from sliding (moving horizontally), and 2) keeping the house from lifting up (moving vertically.

I can tell where you live, you don’t have high winds nor do you live in a high seismic area. Where I live we use 3” square and 1/8” thick washers for those anchor bolts and they are 24” oc.  The sole plate would pull through the anchor bolts with those small washers.

Comment: Thanks lee. To the southwest is,all fields by me. Lately we have had 60mph plus wind gusts. So hopefully they hold up.

Comment: So you think there are too tight by tightening them with a socket wrench?  Yea, they say in order to pass inspection those needed to be tight when I questioned the loose one in plain site. So idk, if its just tge foundation and wood shrinking over time after settling.

Comment: Gusts of 60 mph is a puff. I wouldn’t worry about it. Yes it needs to be very tight. A socket wrench is fine, but don’t over tighten and split the plate.

Comment: Lol, okay sounds good!